# Теория заговора браузеров

Tags: google-chrome, браузер, тестирование

Начну сразу так: если есть желание обсудить мой выбор, либо спорность темы, просьба от этого воздержаться. Меня интересует только ответ на вопрос.

Есть у меня любимый браузер(опера, если кому не терпится похоливарить). И все с ним было хорошо примерно до появления хрома. С момента, когда этот мячик нормально встал на ноги (~6-8 версия), стал замечать нехарактерные тормоза. Причем не только у своего браузера, но и у остальных, кроме Хрома. Так как я столь наивен, что не верю, что у всех проблемы совпали с выходом ПО, но при этом вполне верю в теорию заговора(как уже, кто помнит, было. Что привело к выпилу весьма перспективного браузера), хотелось бы либо окончательно развеять дурные мысли и принять, что и правда все совпадение, просто все отстали, либо наоборот укрепиться в мысли.

Дело в том, что многие, кто юзает джиквери, подключает ее с гугльаппс, да и вообще джиквери может затачиваться под какой-то один браузер. Значит, только pure js, только хардкор.

Фабула:

Хочу синтетический тест, который максимально исключит тлетворное влияние корпораций добра и зла, позволив действительно оценить скорость работы и рендера. Понятно, что известные, типа sun-spidera тут не прокатят. 
В связи с чем вопрос: может, кто такое писал? Либо знает как пишутся подобные сложные тесты?
100500 раз синус в цикле в каждой из 100500 ячеек DIVной таблицы и я могу запустить вычислять, но это слишком узко.

Comment: ты не думал на желтую прессу поработать? странный в общем вопрос от тебя... больше похоже на нытью неочем.

Comment: по-моему всё очевидно: V8 очень быстрый движок, многие горе скриптеры пишут скрипты, тестируемые на этом движке, как ни странно, но из-за своей скорости и приличной оптимизации часто встречаемых ошибок(глобальные переменные, избыточные замыкания), даже криво написанный код работает приемлимо в плане скорости, поэтому код идёт в продакшен, что негативно сказывается на менее мощных движках

P.S. не пойму за что минусуют вопрос

Comment: Эх...@knes - не @knes...собственно, в чем вопрос? В том, что глючит хром?

---
Но минусов кто поналяпал-то? Может, мы просто не так понимаем вопрос...или @knes`а кто-то взломал, например =)

Comment: @Spectre - потому-что скандалы, интриги, расследования, причем тут скриптеры то?

По поводу просто все отстали - так и есть, особенно это заметно на старых машинах.

"да и вообще джиквери может затачиваться под какой-то один браузер", так и есть, но этот браузер не хром, а IE.

"подключает ее с гугльаппс" и что с того? ну подключай с офф сайта если такая жестокая паранойя.

"только pure js, только хардкор" - это да, но явно не по причине паранойи.

PS: @knes - сразу не увидел что вопрос от вас, может быть вы сильно устали и стоит отдохнуть? Если проще - это что? :)

Comment: И еще - не совсем понял, а в чем собственно вопрос?

@Asen - ну я например минусовал, как писал выше тов @Gorets - это, скорее, похоже на статью из желтой прессы :D Не хром тормозит, наоборот - "...у остальных, **кроме Хрома**..."

Comment: Есть фреймворк, заточенный под webkit, назвыается zepto - это мини jquery без кроссбраузерности. для мобильных webkit'ов очень подходит.
По поводу того, что оперу зажимают... Да пофигу, ну медленнее, зато удобная и в использовании и в разработке. Среди меня и моей мамы firefox сдулся, хорошо, что у оперы есть вот такой полярный в плане направления развития соперник как хром (дилетантское мнение, будем считать "имхо").

Все будет хорошо :)

Comment: >"...похоже на статью из желтой прессы..."

>"...больше похоже на нытью..."

по-моему кто-то не заметил ключевую часть вопроса про тесты производительности

Comment: @Spectre - вопрос не так в тесте, как в том, для чего он нужен. А нужен он по причине необоснованной паранойи ( либо батхертом по поводу того, что опера чуть медленее работает :) )

Грубо говоря возникает вопрос - зачем? Если задача не имеет смысла, то кому она нужна? Или кто-то действительно думает о том, что во всем том, что описал ТС есть какой-то смысл и причина описанных явлений?

######[по теме](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: >Грубо говоря возникает вопрос - зачем?

как бы это не было печально, но у меня такой вопрос возникает на многие сдешние вопросы

Comment: Н-да... 

Думал что-то полезное-интересное про измерение производительности сложных диалоговых программ (браузеров) узнаю,

но видно не судьба.

Всех заговоры волнуют.

Comment: @Gorets, не думал: они в жизни не будут проверять о чем пишут. А я как раз хочу проверить. Почему я не написал только "хочу тест"? Потому что мне тут же бы накидали ссылок на санспайдера или аналог.

@AlexWindHope, баттхёртом. Но опять же, если что-то менять, то менять на что-то объективно хорошее. Хром мне видится первым кандидатом, но хочется опереться на независимый тест.

@Asen, не никто не взламывал. Вопрос в том как(и можно ли) быстро написать тест. Хром не так сильно глючит, как слишком много себе позволяет без спроса. И это уже не паранойя, а подтвержденный факт.

Comment: @avp, я тоже так думал. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За некоторыми бразерами было замечено, что они видят, что на них запускают тест и симулировали его с большой скоростью:)

Могу посоветовать только одно - берете стандартный тест, дальше сильно рефакторите (переименовываете переменные, немного переставляете местами участки кода, заменяете код на эквивалентный). Генерируете 5-10 вариантов скрипта. Дальше тестим эти варианты. Так как код у нас эквивалентный, то результаты для одного браузера не должны сильно отличаться. Если начинает отличаться - споймали симулянта.

Comment: А при этом обязательно одевать на голову шапочку из фольги?

Comment: "...**они** видят..." искусственный интеллект? :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, чтобы опознать тест, чаще всего достаточно взглянуть на адрес сервера. =.=

@Gorets, обязательно. И очки такие с разноцветными и разноформенными стеклами. XD